# Use other pairwise distance metrics in scikit-learn for KNN besides p-norm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, distance, knn

For [scikit-learn's KNN package](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-nearest-neighbors), can one specify a pairwise distance metric (from the package `sklearn.metrics.pairwise`) that isn't the p-norm, or Minkowski distance? For example, could I use the [RBF kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel)? Or even the [cosine distance](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the BallTree algorithm that is used to compute fast exact NN search on low to medium number of dimensions cannot work with arbitrary metrics.

Comment: Not even with the brute force option?

Comment: It would be possible to implement kNN classification with the bruteforce and an arbitrary function to compute the pairwise distances but not with the current implementation.

Comment: BTW: any pull request is always appreciated (even though we are quite slow at reviewing them right now...)

Comment: Awesome, now watching the scikit-learn github repo. I just may do that, thank you!

Comment: it would be awesome if an arbitrary distance metric can be used by just plugging in the custom distance-calculation function.

Comment: You can plug arbitrary custom metrics as `PyfuncDistance` in the KD-tree implementation of the NN module: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.neighbors